# Brasero 12.04 Precis, cdrecord instead of wodim. cdrtools instead of cdrkit. Plugin only wants wodim

Tags: 12.04, brasero, burning

I've used cdrtools instead of cdrkit in the past, and has no significant problems getting Brasero to accept cdrtools.  However now it seems Brasero will only look for wodim, it even would not accept a symlink pointing cdrecord -> wodim !!! The same obviously goes for mkisofs -> genisoimage, and readcd -> readom.

How can I get Brasero to accept cdrtools? I'm ok with rebuilding the package if nessesary, but not sure where it is specified.  If a ppa already exists for cdrtrools enables brasero, please let me know.  I do not need to be told about Brandon Snider's PPA, I'm already aware how to get cdrtools installed.

If anyone has any knowledge on this, any help in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How someone did it, from Ubuntu Forums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=852085

Comment: Brandon Snider's Launchpad PPA repository for cdrtools should be mentioned for users who haven't come across it:         http://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools

Comment: That link mentions the usage of hardlinks, which might work as I only tried symlinks.  When I try that suggestion, I'll report back and consider acceptance.

Comment: Hardlinks work, Symlinks do not.  Now Brasero still detected my version as 'old', so it's become a wash. Thank you for that forum post, it did point me on an acceptable direction.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools

Can not be more simple. Writing with k3b and cdrecord 3 right now as a test. Nothing more than to add this ppa, install and burn.

I have not tested Brasero though, but this PPA is made for replacing the cdrkit so I assume he though of that too.

Oh, it was mentioned already :)

Comment: Not only was it mentioned in a previous comment, I specifically requested it not be provided.  I understand the thinking, and generally might agree if talking about a more obscure subject.  In this case, the PPA link is very easy to locate, it's littered all over the internet.

Comment: And I also notice, your answer is not even attempting to address my question.  It might be an acceptable comment, under a related post, but in this case it's better off deleted.  However I do appreciate your time, regardless of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to wrap my head around all the issues but I think I know why your having problems. I have also been struggling with the switch to `cdrtools` and `mkisofs`. As far as Brasero 3.4.1 is concerned (I assume you have a similar version) there is a directory `/usr/lib/brasero3-1/plugins` which seems to be the basis for how Brasero is configured. This directory contains a file called `wodim.so`, which is a binary.

I'm afraid I have no idea how to change this. Even more annoying is the fact that the `xcdroast` which is available in the repositories also insists on having `wodim`.

My suggestion is to use `cdrtools` on the command line. I'm avoiding `wodim` because I have had significant problems with it including (but not restricted to) wasting a large number of blank CDs because it simply did not work with Brasero... "An error occurred"

Sorry, I can't give you better advice at this stage.

Comment: I*ve experimented a bit now and discovered that using symlinks does work for me. The difference to TechZilla's assertion above is probably due to differences in our installations. I guess everyone will need to try it for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The PPA now has a resolution to the crafty Brasero checks in place to make sure you're really using Wodim, Readom, and Genisoimage. There are scripts I developed with Jorg Schilling and Clement Lefebvre to act as middle-men -- fooling Brasero into thinking it's actually using Kit, when it's really using Tools. All features of the Kit plugins are enabled at that point.

Plugins for mkisofs, cdrecord, and readcd are available in Brasero, but they go unbuilt. A different solution would be to rebuild Brasero locally and enable the Tools plugins, installing them in a separate package called "brasero-cdrtools". That's undoubtedly beyond most users.